# Java extends generic prototype

Tags: java, generics

I have few classes that implements some interface. Now I want to create new class, which can extend one of them, based on runtime calculation while using interfaces methods. Let's talk in code:

```
public interface Interface {
    public void doSomething();
}

public class A implements Interface {
    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
}

public class B implements Interface {
    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("hi");
    }
}
```

These are existing classes, so now I need to do something like this (which is not working of course):

```
public class C<T extends Interface> extends T {
    public void doSomethingElse() {
        this.doSomething();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        C c;
        if(isSomethingLoaded) {
            c = new C<A>();
        } else {
            c = new C<B>();
        }
        c.doSomethingElse();
    }
}
```

Is it possible somehow, except the way that I pass argument Interface other to C's constructor and store to class property..?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A class cannot extend from its type parameter.

Use composition instead of inheritance:

```
public class C<T extends Interface> {
    private final T foo;

    public C(T foo){
       this.foo = foo;
    }

    public void doSomethingElse() {
        foo.doSomething();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        C<?> c;
        if(isSomethingLoaded) {
            c = new C<>(new A());
        } else {
            c = new C<>(new B());
        }
        c.doSomethingElse();
    }
}
```

You might even not need the type parameter here, but just use the interface type as argument/ member type.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot something - If I need to use method doSomething() in main, I have to explicitly implement it, right? Or is there other way? 
E: in different words, if I want to have C implements same Interface

Comment: @tcigler Yes, you have either to implement/ wrap doSomething() or provide a getter for foo.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's situations like this which show why we have the rule of favouring composition over inheritance. Consider this solution using composition:

```
public class Test {
    public interface Interface {
        void doSomething();
    }

    public static class A implements Interface {
        @Override
        public void doSomething() {
            System.out.println("Doing A");
        }
    }

    public static class B implements Interface {
        @Override
        public void doSomething() {
            System.out.println("Doing B");
        }
    }

    public static class C implements Interface {
        private Interface composedWith;

        public C(Interface i) {
            this.composedWith = i;
        }

        @Override
        public void doSomething() {
            this.composedWith.doSomething();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        C c;
        if(isSomethingLoaded) {
            c = new C(new A());
        } else {
            c = new C(new B());
        }
        c.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Personally, I feel this is a clearer and move flexible way of achieving what you are trying to do.